# Segmentation Fault while Splitting an Array containing IP Address

Tags: c, string, pointers, split, segmentation-fault

After splitting the IP address, I want to pick out the last element i.e 15 and increment it but after getting 192 in `buff` when it goes to 1st case, i get segmentation fault!

Why it can't go further? What may be the problem?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

char str[] = "192.168.10.15"; 
char str1[12];
char *str2, *str3, *str4, *str5;
unsigned char bytes[4];
int i = 0;

int lastelem; 

char* buff = (char *)malloc(20);
buff = strtok(str,".");


while (buff != NULL)
{
   printf("%s\n",buff);

   switch(i)
   {
       case 0: str2=buff;
       break;

       case 1: str3=buff;
       break;

       case 2: str4=buff;
       break;

       case 3: str5=buff;
       break;
   } 

   lastelem=atoi(str5);
   sprintf(str5, "%d",lastelem);

   bytes[i] = (unsigned char)atoi(buff);
   buff = strtok(NULL,".");
   i++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `discards`???? wow..

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: one day, your message about not casting `malloc()` *will* get through!

Comment: This `char* buff = (char *)malloc(20);
buff = strtok(str,".");` leaks `20` bytes of memory. Also you cannot copy an array per assignment.

Comment: `sscanf(str,"%d.%d.%d.%d",&n1,&n2,&n3,&n4);`

Comment: @alk Sir i didn't get your last line :(

Comment: In  C you cannot copy all elements of an array at once using the `=` operator.

Comment: yes obviously....!!! thank you :)

Comment: @Bathsheba I admit having somewhat given up on that one. But Sourav Ghosh has taken over with a remarkable fervour :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, in the very first iteration, (*or, for that case, on any other iteration, except when `case 3` is hit*)

```
 lastelem=atoi(str5);
```

`str5` is uninitialized., so it's invoking [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should use `str5` only after it has been assigned. You can use a flag, if you want, to mark the *hit* on `case 3:` or, put the code under the `case` block itself.

Also, you don't need to allocate memory to `buff`, as you're overwriting it with the returned pointer from `strtok()`. That creates a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: @DeepJyotiGharphalia easiest way, move all the `str5` related code under case 3...

Answer (score 2):

Move your `str5` related stuff, inside `case3`

```
case 3: str5 = buff;
lastelem = atoi(str5);
sprintf(str5, "%d", lastelem);
break;
```

Also, no need to allocate memory to buff, you are not copying something in it, you are just pointing something, this will cause a memory leak in your code.

Comment: Just change this line  `char* buff = (char *)malloc(20);` to

    char* buff = NULL;